# Coding using Jquery_mobile

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
<script>
    $('Machine_location_id').observe("change", function (event) {
        console.log("here");
        var pars = "loc_no=" + $F('Machine_location_id');
        new Ajax.Updater('load_floor', '/adminctrls/loadfloormachine', {
            parameters: pars
        });
    });

    function load_floor() {
        console.log("here");
        var pars = "floor_no=" + $F('Machine_floor_id');
        new Ajax.Updater('load_cubicle', '/adminctrls/loadcubiclemachine', {
            parameters: pars
        });
    }
</script>
```

In this ajax code, the floors under that location should be loaded when a location is selected. This is working fine but I am unable to load them in jquery mobile, how can I fix this?

Comment: Please try to make this post more readable.

Comment: What..... is this jquery?

Comment: why not using $.ajax()?

Comment: no its not working with  $.ajax()